# Search for questions excluding certain tags

Tags: feature-request, questions, filtering

I'm interested in Silverlight but not Windows Phone,

When I click on my favorite tag "Silverlight" I see dozens of Windows Phone tagged questions. Before Windows Phone revolution I could easily find and answer questions for my area of interest.

Is there a way of querying `c#+silverlight` but **not** `windows-phone`

Comment: Have you tried putting [windows-phone] on your ignored list?

Comment: In fact I didn't think it :D But I've tried just now. It still shows questions but blurred.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/silverlight+-windows-phone

Comment: seems better for me!

Comment: Go to Preferences and select Hide Ignored Tags

Comment: Yeah! This is first time I introduced with Preferences. Setup completed.Answer Accepted ! with Mysticials :)

Answer (score 3):

If ignored tags isn't cutting it for you, you could try this search term:

> [silverlight] -[windows-phone] -[windows-phone-7] -[windows-phone-8] -"Windows Phone"

[Demo (53, 848)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsilverlight%5D+-%5Bwindows-phone%5D+-%5Bwindows-phone-7%5D+-%5Bwindows-phone-8%5D+-%22Windows+Phone%22)

Or for a simpler, but less accurate one, you could just use:

> [silverlight] -"Windows Phone"

[Demo (59, 462)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsilverlight%5D%20-%22Windows%20Phone%22)

Comment: Thank you, realized that just me don't know this :D

Comment: @DavutGürbüz No problems! Yeah search is **very powerful**!